# Difference between Fasttext .vec and .bin file

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, fasttext

I recently downloaded fasttext pretrained model for english. I got two files:

1. wiki.en.vec
2. wiki.en.bin

I am not sure what is the difference between the two files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `.vec` files contain only the aggregated word vectors, in plain-text. The `.bin` files *in addition* contain the model parameters, and crucially, the vectors for all the n-grams.

So if you want to encode words you did not train with using those n-grams (FastText's famous "subword information"), you *need* to find an API that can handle FastText `.bin` files (most only support the `.vec` files, however...).

Comment: How do you actually work with the `.bin`  file? I've tried `open(FILENAME, "rb")` but then not sure how to actually access the weight matrix after that

Comment: @information_interchange did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: Please take a look at the official documentation for the Python API: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python#saving-and-loading-a-model-object

Comment: @information_interchange you can do model = fasttext.load_model("embedding.bin") to load a model object.

Answer (score 16):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/README.md) says,

> `model.vec` is a text file containing the word vectors, one per line.
>   `model.bin` is a binary file containing the parameters of the model
>   along with the dictionary and all hyper parameters.

In other words, `.vec` file format is the same as `.txt` file format, and you could use it in other applications (for example, to exchange data between your FastText model and your Word2Vec model since `.vec` file is similar to `.txt` file generated by Word2Vec). And the `.bin` file could be used if you want to continue training the vectors or to restart the optimization.

Comment: I agree with the highlighted part but we can further train .vec files also on other data/corpus .