# How can I get a vec file from a bin file?

Tags: python, alignment, unsupervised-learning, fasttext

I m trying to align my model with `fasttext unsupervised.py` https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE. I trained my model with `fasttext` and I got the binary file `model.bin`. When I use unsupervised.py I get the

```
error: ValueError: model.bin has wrong file format
```

What is wrong? Do I have to have a `.vec` file? How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information about the difference between .bin and .vec files, you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118678/difference-between-fasttext-vec-and-bin-file).

In any case, **MUSE expects .vec files**.

**If you want to convert a .bin file to a .vec file, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58342618/10883094) will probably help you.**

Answer (score 0):

The Puthon Gensim package can load Facebook FastText `.bin` models with its [`FastText.load_facebook_model()` method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model):

```
ft_model = FastText.load_facebook_model(path_to_bin)
```

Then, save out just the vectors from the model's included `.wv` word-vector as a plain-text `.vec` file using the [`KeyedVectors' method` .save_word2vec_format()`with the`binary=False` option](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.save_word2vec_format):

```
ft_model.wv.save_word2vec_format('ft_model.vec')
```