# How to retrofit a fasttext model?

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

I have read various research papers that one can retrofitting a fasttext model to improve its accuracy (https://github.com/mfaruqui/retrofitting). However I am having trouble on how to implement it.

The github link above, will take one vector file and retrofitting it, output another vector file. I can load it using gensim library. However, since it is a vector file, it is no longer a model and it will not predict OOV (out-of-vocabulary) words. This makes it pointless. Is there a way to retrain the model somehow so it has better accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand by reading the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4166.pdf) and browsing the [repository](https://github.com/mfaruqui/retrofitting), **the proposed methodology only allows to improve the quality of the vectors** (.vec) given in input.

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118678/difference-between-fasttext-vec-and-bin-file), fastText's ability to represent out-of-vocabulary words is inherent in the .bin model (which contains the vectors for all the n-grams).

**As you too may have understood, there is no out-of-the-box way to retrofit a fastText model, using the proposed methodology.**

Comment: Indeed, the method only works on a fixed set of vectors - not a complete FastText model, with all of its subword info. But a thought for the asker: if there are some fixed set of OOV words of most interest to you – perhaps those named in the lexicon – you could conceivably retrieve *all* words of interest (both in-vocab & OOV) from the FT model, put those in a static `.vec` file, and try the technique on that. You'd not have a full FastText model - but you would have all your new retrofit vectors for the fixed list of words-of-interest.